# Inverse relation including Hypergeometric function

Tags: calculus, power-series, inverse, hypergeometric-function

For the following function:
\begin{equation}
y\left( _{2}F_{1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p}, 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)t \right)=t
\end{equation}
I am trying to find an explicit formula. Therefore I consider the following relation:
\begin{equation}
x=_{2}F_{1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p}, 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)t
\end{equation}
where $_{2}F_{1}\left(a,b,c;t\right)$ the ordinary hypergeometric function. Moreover, if my math up until now is correct, it also holds:
\begin{equation}
_{2}F_{1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p}, 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)=t \left( 1-t^p\right)^{1/p} \quad _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{2}{p}, 1, 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)
\end{equation}
resulting in the following:
\begin{equation}
x=t \left( 1-t^p\right)^{1/p} \quad _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{2}{p}, 1, 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)
\end{equation}
I would like to solve for $t$ but I have reached the case where:
\begin{equation}
t^p(1-t^p)=\left( \frac{x}{_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{2}{p}, 1, 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)} \right)^p
\end{equation}
and it leads to an implicit relation.

I would like to ask whether it is possible in this case to solve for $t$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do the stars denote ordinary products or convolution products ?

Comment: Just ordinary products, I used them since the i left index $2$ at the hypergeometric $F$ would go along to pair with the variable and I did not want this.

Comment: Could you give some infrmation about the origins of the problem ? Surprisingly, this gives rather often a clue...

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, the whole thing is that i have the function $y(_{2} F_{1}\left( 1-1/p,1/p,1+1/p \right)t)=t$ and I would like to acquire the explicit formula for $y(t)$. I will try to add this to the main body of the question but probably tomorrow.

Comment: I think$$_{2}F_{1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p}; 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)=t \left( 1-t^p\right)^{1/p}\; _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{2}{p}, 1; 1+\frac{1}{p}; t^p \right)
$$is always wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the closed form for an inverse function by rewriting with [the incomplete beta function $\text B_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28x%2Ca%2Cb%29)

$$x=\,_2\text F_1\left(1-\frac1p,\frac 1p;1+\frac1p;t^p\right)t=\frac{\text B_{t^p}\left(\frac1p,\frac1p\right)}p$$

Therefore, $t(x)$ is an [inverse beta regularized $\text I^{-1}_s(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversebetaregularized) expression:

$$t=\sqrt[p]{\text I^{-1}_\frac{px}{\text B\left(\frac1p,\frac1p\right)}\left(\frac1p,\frac1p\right)}= \sqrt[p]{\text I^{-1}_\frac{2^{\frac2p-1}\Gamma\left(\frac1p+\frac12\right)x}{\sqrt\pi\Gamma\left(\frac1p+1\right)}\left(\frac1p,\frac1p\right)};0\le \frac{px}{\text B\left(\frac1p,\frac1p\right)} \le1,p>0$$

which [**works**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B+eulergamma-2F1%281-1%2Fe%2C1%2Fe%2C+1+%2B+1%2Fe%2C+t%5Ee%29t%2C20%5D%2C+t%3Dinversebetaregularized%28e+eulergamma%2Fbeta%281%2Fe%2C1%2Fe%29%2C1%2Fe%2C1%2Fe%29%5E%281%2Fe%29)

You can “generalize” the function by transforming it if it is meant to be periodic. Also, this function can be put into a form with $\text I^{-1}_y\left(\frac1p,\frac12\right)$